# SQL Server : SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Table] WHERE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm new to SQL Server, and I'm trying to select a range between two dates.

My column is `varchar` (format: `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss`), but if I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Table] 
WHERE [Column] BETWEEN 'lower date' AND 'max date'
```

the result is every date that begins with the first two search option. In my case "dd" *(dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss)*.

Is there a solution, without changing the column from `varchar` to `datetime`?

Comment: You have dedicated column types for dates. Using `VARCHAR` is hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: i tried to convert the column but i get some error.

Comment: If it looks like a datetime, smells like a datetime, quacks like a datetime - then **IT IS** a datetime and should be **stored as such!** That's the **whole point** of having those datatypes - and storing everything as strings - just because it's easier not to think about datatypes - then results in troubles like this. You **avoid these** by **always** (no exceptions!) using the **most appropriate** datatype - for a date & time, that's `DATETIME2(n)` (in SQL Server **2008** and higher)

Comment: @szakyaty "i tried to convert the column but i get some error." - that should not be an excuse for forging a rod for your own back, by storing data in an inappropriate format. Why not ask on SO for help fixing THAT error, then this one will go away. If you don't fix that error, crap like this will plague you forever more

Comment: The other comments are right -- if this column will strictly carry a `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` value, then it should be normalized as such. It is both less efficient and less secure to use a `VARCHAR` here. You may consider researching [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to learn more about best practices for designing and maintaining a database schema.

Comment: finally i solved my problem. i deleted the table and recreated with datetime column. THNX 4 your support.

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel Slomka's answer is close, but uses an incorrect date format. You should be using format 104 (German), according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles):

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Table]
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, [Column], 104) BETWEEN 'lower date' AND 'max date';
```

Comment: It should be noted that if this table grows large then querying it for date ranges by converting all the dates will have horrendous performance implications because it will prevent the use of indexes. I'd implore you to restate in any answer of this ilk that the OP should do it properly from the start; he's new, he's learning and he's absolutely done this one wrong and in the worst way possible. If he takes away from this experience that "this is how dates should be stored" as does it forever more "because that's he way I've always done it" then that's a huge problem. Nip it in the bud

Comment: finally i solved my problem. i deleted the table and recreated with datetime column. THNX 4 your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you column is varchar, you can try

```
select * from table where CONVERT(Datetime, column, 120) between lower and max
```

Comment: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: No, do not teach someone that a)storing dates as varchar is ok and b)converting every data item in every row (potentially millions of rows, billions of conversions over the life of the app) is acceptable either. It's inefficient on storage, wasteful of cpu cycles, disables indexes and will lead to obscure bugs

Comment: @CaiusJard, while database normalization is a great target to aim for, there are cases where it is impractical to strictly follow those best practices and where deserializing data columns into multiple types can be reasonable. Your comment would be better-targeted toward the OP rather than the answerer.

Comment: Doesn't mean we can't make a judgement call as to what is and isn't reasonable in terms of data storage. Heck if this date has to be stored as a string the least he could do to make his life easier is store it as yyymddhhmmss form - but I made the comment that I did in this case because the op had implied he'd tried to do it correctly and had failed, given up and settled on this poor solution instead. We should really be helping him solve the problem, not the broken solution. Sometimes I try to educate the OPs, other times I try to educate the answerers

Comment: finally i solved my problem. i deleted the table and recreated with datetime column. THNX 4 your support.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that doesn't change the column. It does, however, convert it for the comparison. As you'll see, I create a computed column from your varchar column to be used with your between clause.

```
declare @lowerDate datetime = '20170401'
declare @maxDate datetime = getdate()

if object_id('tempdb..#myTable') is not null drop table #myTable

create table #myTable(VarColumn varchar(64))
insert into #myTable
values
('12.02.2017 08:14:22'),
('30.05.2017 08:14:22')

;with cte as(
select 
    VarColumn
    ,NewColumn = cast(substring(convert(varchar(20),replace(VarColumn,'.','/'),113),4,2) + '/' + substring(convert(varchar(20),replace(VarColumn,'.','/'),113),1,2) + right(convert(varchar(20),replace(VarColumn,'.','/'),113),14) as datetime)
from
    #myTable)

select *
from cte
where NewColumn between @lowerDate and @maxDate
```

Comment: How about making the headline a query that can solve the actual problem- OP said he was struggling converting the column to date so just gave up and used string. IMO the real issue that needs fixing is there, not these band aids to a broken solution

Comment: So what you're saying is; it wouldn't be a huge step to put that advice in?

Comment: Pretty much - but it would be more than that; you'd need as a minimum: rename existing column, add new date time column to table, populate new column with your update query, drop old column

Comment: You’re comical, but that’s outside the scope of this question and would be a duplicate

Comment: finally i solved my problem. i deleted the table and recreated with datetime column. THNX 4 your support.

Comment: oh, so you just lost all that data? I would have created a new table and renamed it personally @SzakyAty and that solution is abstract for most production environments.

Comment: i did not lose the stored data. First i exported the table to excel, changed the datetime format and with a little excel VBA uploaded the new values.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a solution, without changing the column from varchar to datetime?

It depends what you mean by this statement. All the other answers here work by changing the column data from string to datetime every time the query is run, and doing this every time this is massively resource wasteful and needlessly slow compared to the correct alternative.

If you want a solution that doesn't mention the word datetime at all (I.e. By "without changing the column" means no type conversion of the column data shall be performed) then you're going to have to use  SUBSTR to cut your string up and rearrange it to be yyyymmddhhmmss or similar, then it will work for a BETWEEN with string arguments of dates. But even doing that is manipulating table data which automatically means indexes become unusable. The whole purpose of an index is to make searches lookups quick; here you're going out of your way to defeat that mechanism and make your lookups slow, while clearly writing code whose only purpose is to perform a lookup - building poor performance into an application should be avoided, because you may reach a state one day where fixing it is very hard indeed

If all you're trying to do is avoid converting the data type of the column, even though you appreciate that's what you should be doing, I beg you not to do this - you've stated you're new, and learning. You've a responsibility to yourself and to all the users of your software to learn how to do it right, from the start. Please don't be another one of those coders who takes some poor quality way out and end up writing a system  with serious performance and security flaws (this case isn't necessarily a security risk, but if this apparent lack of a desire to do things properly one day also extends to security considerations, that's an even bigger problem)

Ultimately the real answer here, as I've no doubt detected I'm passionate that you implement, is to add another column to your table, use any one of these answers to run an update statement that populates the new column with the datetime equivalent of the string data, and drop the old column. Answers that solve a problem as stated often only invest in the immediate context; I'm hoping to invest in your software engineering future

Comment: You can add computed persisted column to hold equivalent datetime value - this way you don't need manually update it.

Comment: You can, but that would be even more bizarre than doing it properly!

Comment: finally i solved my problem. i deleted the table and recreated with 'datetime' column. THNX 4 your support.

Comment: Fantastic. I'd much appreciate you clicking the tick icon next to this answer, because as it stands it's simultaneously the only answer that is downvoted, and it is also the actual answer to your problem. Placing a green tick lets future visitors know which answer you considered to be the correct one